# SVG: Is there a way to animate the start of a line along a path while leaving the end static?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, svg

I'm trying to animate the start of an svg line along a path while keeping the end of the line at a a static point.

I think the best way to illustrate my problem is with the gifs below. On the left is what I have worked on so far. Each arc is an svg path that animates in using a simple css `rotate()` (see the code below for details).

On the right is what I'm trying to achieve - a line that moves its `x1 and y1` along with the rotating arc while keeping its `x2 and y2` at a static point below the arcs.

I'm not too adept when it comes to svg yet, so if there are any improvements I can make to the markup that help in achieving my goal, then that's fine by me.

[image] [image]

```
const SingleMessage: React.FC<{ index: number, text: string[], fairy: fairyNames, lines: number, prevWidth: number }> = ({ prevWidth, index, text, lines, fairy }) => {
// Width of the message arc - base 11 + 14 for each line of text
const width = 11 + 14 * lines;
// Radius of the arc from 0,0 - offset by prevWidth
const radius = 205.5 + prevWidth + width / 2;
// Calculate the d of the path according to the variables above
const arc = describeArc(0, 0, radius, 89, 180 - ((width) / 2) / radius / (Math.PI / 180));
// Start coordinates of the path (arc) that are used as coordinates for the circle at the start of the arc
const arcStart = arc.split(' ').slice(1, 3);
// Colors for each path
const fairyGradient = fairyColors.get(fairy)?.gradient;
// Ref to the whole svg group in order to animate it using rotate()
const messagesRef = useRef<SVGGElement>(null);

// Rotate the path to 0 on mount (starts at -100deg)
useEffect(() => {
    if (messagesRef.current)
        messagesRef.current.style.transform = "rotate(0)";
}, [messagesRef.current])

return (
    // Rotate the whole group by 100deg in order to initially hide it
    <g className="-rotate-[100deg] transition-transform duration-500" ref={messagesRef}>
        {/* Gradient along the path */}
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id={`gradient${index}`}>
                <stop offset="0%" stopColor={fairyGradient?.[0]} />
                <stop offset="100%" stopColor={fairyGradient?.[1]} />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        {/* Arc container of the message */}
        <path id={`msg${index}`} d={arc} fill="none" stroke="#fff" strokeWidth={width} strokeLinecap="round" className="drop-shadow-[4px_4px_0_rgba(0,0,0,0.25)]" />
        {/* Border around the arc */}
        <path d={arc} stroke={`url(#gradient${index})`} strokeWidth={width - 4} strokeLinecap="round" fill='none' />
        {/* Circle at the sart of the message */}
        <circle cx={arcStart[0]} cy={arcStart[1]} r={width / 2 - 1} fill={`url(#gradient${index})`} stroke="#fff" strokeWidth="2" />
        {/* Text inside the message */}
        <text color="#446688" fontSize="12px" fontFamily="'Kiwi Maru'" className="text-outline-light">
            <textPath startOffset={width / 2 - 1 + 5} href={`#msg${index}`}>
                <tspan x="0" alignmentBaseline={lines > 1 ? "before-edge" : "central"} dy={lines > 1 ? -(width / 2) + 4 : -1} >{text[0]}</tspan>
                {text.length > 1 && text.slice(1).map((v, i) => <tspan key={index.toString() + i} x="0" alignmentBaseline="before-edge" dy="1em">{v}</tspan>)}
            </textPath>
        </text>
    </g>
);
```

Comment: You would need to animate the rotation yourself in JS using `requestAnimationFrame()`  etc.  At each iteraction, calculate the centre of the circle, and then use those coordinates to update a `<line> element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Paul's suggestion, I read up on `requestAnimationFrame()` and created a hook that does the animation instead of using css transitions.

I got the information I needed from [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe-with-react-hooks/) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

Here's the code for anyone interested:

```
export const useAnimationFrame = (duration: number, delay: number, callback: (deltaTime: number) => void) => {
    // Request ID from requestAnimationFrame()
    const requestRef = useRef<number>();
    // Start Time of the animation
    const startTimeRef = useRef<number>();
    // Time of the previous animationframe
    const previousTimeRef = useRef<number>(0);

    // animate() is called recursivly until the duration is over
    const animate = (time: number) => {
        // Set the start time...
        if (startTimeRef.current === undefined) {
            startTimeRef.current = time;
        }

        // ...to calculate the elapsed time
        const elapsed = time - startTimeRef.current;

        // Do the animation if we have a new frame
        if (previousTimeRef.current !== time) {
            callback(elapsed);
        }

        // Only recurse if we still haven't reached the duration of the animation
        if (elapsed < duration) {
            previousTimeRef.current = time;
            requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }
    }

    // Start the animation
    useEffect(() => {
        // Add a delay if necessary
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(animate), delay);
        // Cleanup
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            requestRef.current && cancelAnimationFrame(requestRef.current)
        };
    }, []);
}
```

```
...
    // End coordinates of the line connecting the start of the arc with the fairy icon
    const [[x, y], setXY] = useState([radius.toString(), "0"]);
    // Current rotation of the arc
    const [rotation, setRotation] = useState(-90);

    // Animation for the rotation of the arc
    useAnimationFrame(animationDuration, index < 5 ? index * 500 : 0, elapsed => {
        // Set the current rotation of the arc
        const currRotation = Math.min(0, elapsed * 90 / animationDuration - 90);
        setRotation(currRotation);

        // For all messages after the five predefined, animate the line together with the arc
        if (index >= 5) {
            const currEndAngle = Math.min(endAngle, elapsed * 90 / animationDuration + 90);
            const circlePos = describeArc(0, 0, radius, 90, currEndAngle).split(' ');
            setXY([circlePos[1], circlePos[2]]);
        }
    })

    return (
        <g>
            {index >= 5 && <line stroke='#fff' strokeWidth="3" x1="200" y1="550" x2={x} y2={y} />}
            {/* Rotate the whole group by 90deg in order to initially hide it */}
            <g className="-rotate-90" style={{ transform: `rotate(${rotation}deg)` }}>
...
```